# $q$-characters of quantum affine algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

The theory of $q$-characters for quantum affine algebras are studied in [The q-characters of representations of quantum affine algebras and deformations of W-algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810055), [Combinatorics of q-characters of finite-dimensional representations of quantum affine algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911112), and [Spectra of Tensor Products of Finite Dimensional Representations of Yangians](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869385711234).

I think that the following results are true. But I didn't find their proofs in the above references. Do the results follow from the general theory of $q$-characters? Thank you very much.

Let $m_1, \ldots, m_k$ be dominant monomials in $\chi_q(M_1)  \chi_q(M_2)$, where $M_1, M_2$ are two simple $U_q(\hat{g})$-modules and $\chi_q(M)$ is the $q$-character of $M$. Then we have the following two results.

Suppose that $m_i$ is not contained in any $\chi_q(L(m_j))$, $j \neq i$. Then $L(m_i)$ is an irreducible subfactor of $M_1 \otimes M_2$. Here $L(m_i)$ is the simple $U_q(\hat{g})$-module with highest $l$-weight $m_i$.

Suppose that $L(m_i)$ is a subfactor of $M_1 \otimes M_2$. Suppose that $m_j$ appears in $\chi_q(M_1) \chi_q(M_2)$ with multiplicity $p$ and $m_j$ appears in $\chi_q(L(m_i))$ with multiplicity $p$. Then $m_j$ is not a subfactor of $M_1 \otimes M_2$.